# Unique id for combination of Latitude - Longitude

Tags: bash, libreoffice

I am new in using Linux (kubuntu 13).

I have a LibreOffice Calc table containing one column with Latitude and one with Longitude. What I want to do is for every unique combination of Latitude and Longitude a unique number to be assigned in a third column. By doing that every point represented by the (Lat/Long) will have a unique id number. How would I do this in bash shell?

Comment: You could do it in python quite easily...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been very specific in the details, so I will presume that your file contains only the data that you have mentioned, and the formatting is consistent. I will also presume that your file is white-space delimited.

Hence, the input file looks something like this.

```
1°2'3" 4°5'6"
2°3'4" 5°6'7"
```

or this

```
1.23 4.56
2.34 5.67
```

In that case, then run this command

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$1$2}' /path/to/input.csv > output.csv
```

which will produce this

```
1°2'3" 4°5'6" 1°2'3"4°5'6"
2°3'4" 5°6'7" 2°3'4"5°6'7"
```

or this

```
1.23 4.56 1.234.56
2.34 5.67 2.345.67
```

If your file potentially contains duplicates, you can remove them with the following command instead.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$1$2}' /path/to/input.csv | sort | uniq > output.csv
```